# Expect mocked library function to have been called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, auth0

I am mocking a function in a library (auth0), this way:

```
jest.mock('@auth0/auth0-react', () => ({
    useAuth0: () => {
        return {
            logout: jest.fn(),
        }
    }
}));
```

During my test, how can I expect the logout function to have been called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to manually [mock a node_module](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules), you need to create a mock module file. Manual mocks are defined by writing a module in a **mocks**/ subdirectory immediately adjacent to the module. In your case the mock should be placed in the `__mocks__` directory adjacent to `node_modules`.

root/`__mocks__`/@auth0/auth0-react.js

```
'use strict';

const handleRedirectCallback = jest.fn(() => ({ appState: {} }));
const buildLogoutUrl = jest.fn();
const buildAuthorizeUrl = jest.fn();
const checkSession = jest.fn();
const getTokenSilently = jest.fn();
const getTokenWithPopup = jest.fn();
const getUser = jest.fn();
const getIdTokenClaims = jest.fn();
const isAuthenticated = jest.fn(() => false);
const loginWithPopup = jest.fn();
const loginWithRedirect = jest.fn();
const logout = jest.fn();

export const Auth0Client = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    buildAuthorizeUrl,
    buildLogoutUrl,
    checkSession,
    handleRedirectCallback,
    getTokenSilently,
    getTokenWithPopup,
    getUser,
    getIdTokenClaims,
    isAuthenticated,
    loginWithPopup,
    loginWithRedirect,
    logout,
  };
});
```

test.ts (in case you are writing test in typescript)

```
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
const clientMock = mocked(new Auth0Client({ client_id: '', domain: '' }));

describe('auth0 test', () => {
   it('should check logout is called', async () => {
      await my_logout_function();
      expect(clientMock.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
});
```

test.js (in case you are writing tests in javascript)

```
const clientMock = new Auth0Client({ client_id: '', domain: '' });

describe('auth0 test', () => {
   it('should check logout is called', async () => {
      await my_logout_function();
      expect(clientMock.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
});
```

Comment: seems neat but i don 't understand where that mocked function comes from

Comment: My bad. I've edited the answer. In case you are using ts-jest to write tests in typescript mocked helper function will provide typings for your module. If you are using javascript, you can completely skip this.
https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/test-helpers/